# Connecting to database at a servlet or at a managed bean

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee

I am new to javaEE and trying to make database connection. I can do it but i think my way of doing it is inefficient. Here is what i do:

```
static String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bank";
  static String username="root";
  static String password="";

  static Connection con=null;

  public static void connect ()
  {
      try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);
       System.out.println("Connected!");

      } 
      catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("not connected");

      }

  }

    public void someFunctiontoConnectToDB{
          try {
        connect();
                    DO_THE_QUERY.....etc
          }
    }
```

Here is my problem, this method works fine, but i have to duplicate the same code whenever i try to connect to DB in another servlet or managed bean. I tried to create a class for connection and pass the Connection c as the parameter, but this time when it returns from the connection class, Connection object becomes null. Is there any other way i can make connection easier, and without code duplication?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that will connect to database and make a method return the connection.

When you want to use connection in other classes, you simply call that method.

Or else what you can do is

1. Create a `ServletContextListener`
2. Add database connection code in the listener.
3. Add a method to return `connection`
4. Use it whenever required.

Comment: Returning Connection object seems a good idea, i will try it thank you

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible try to get into JPA, it makes life much easier.

But if you are stuck with JDBC, here is a good approach for abstracting and encapsulating the Database Layer [Core J2EE Patterns - Data Access Object](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)

In a summary for your case I would do something like this:

The DAOFactory:

```
class MySqlDAOFactory {
  static String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bank";
  static String username="root";
  static String password="";
  static private Connection con;

  public static void createConnection() {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);
      System.out.println("Connected!");

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("not connected");

    }
  }

  public static BankDAO getBankDAO() {
    return new BankDAO(con);
  }
}
```

And the BankDAO:

```
class BankDAO {
  Connection con;

  public BankDAO(Connection con) {
    this.con = con;
  }

  public Account getAccountFor(String name) {
    //JDBC Operations
    return acc;
  }
}
```

In your Managed Bean or Servlet:

```
public void someFunction() {
  MySqlDAOFactory.createConnection();
  BankDAO dao = MySqlDAOFactory.getBankDAO();
  //get other DAOs

  Account acc = dao.getAccountFor("bob");
}
```